# Is there a downside to using a dictionary for Javascript Namespacing?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var myJS = {
   initialPosition:null,
   previousPosition: {},
```

It seems as though this might effect performance, based on JavaScripts use of hashtables.

Comment: As I remembered, objects in javascript seems to be allocated in heap so it might be not so efficient to use objects, but not very sure. You are possibly doing pre-optimization anyway, I suggest you let js engines do their job and you do yours.